# How to get data remotely from mySQL database installed in raspberry pi in WinForms application?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms

I'm collecting data of sensors on my raspberry pi mySQL database, and theese data need to be used on an windows form application. The following steps have been done:

The bind-address is commented out on raspberry config file

The connection between windows form application and raspberry mySQL database is successful with the following code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnectionStringBuilder conn_string = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    conn_string.Server = "192.168.x.xxx";
    conn_string.Port = 3306;
    conn_string.UserID = "root";
    conn_string.Password = "password";
    conn_string.Database = "db_name";
    MySqlConnection MyCon = new MySqlConnection(conn_string.ToString());

    try
    {
        MyCon.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Open");
        MyCon.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Close");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

[image]

When I try to get data with the following code and same connection

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    MySqlConnectionStringBuilder conn_string = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    conn_string.Server = "192.168.x.xxx";
    conn_string.Port = 3306;
    conn_string.UserID = "root";
    conn_string.Password = "password";
    conn_string.Database = "db_name";
    MySqlConnection MyCon = new MySqlConnection(conn_string.ToString());

    MyCon.Open();

    MySqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tab_name", MyCon);
    sqlDa.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    DataTable dtblData = new DataTable();
    sqlDa.Fill(dtblData);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dtblData;

}
```

This message appears

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Procedure or function '`SELECT * FROM`tab_name`WHERE 1`' cannot be found in database '`db_name`'.'

[image]

There are about 150000 data in specified database/table can be seen with following picture. 
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"SELECT * FROM tab_name"` is not a stored procedure, so `CommandType.StoredProcedure` is incorrect.

make it

```
sqlDa.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

or remove entirely, because `CommandType.Text` is default.

the remaining commandType should work with table name:

```
MySqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new MySqlDataAdapter("tab_name", MyCon);
sqlDa.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
```